# Prove by induction that $3n^2 + 3n + 1 \leq 2(3^n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

This is a proof within another proof but I am stuck on the last few steps of:
Prove by induction that $3n^2 + 3n + 1 \leq 2(3^n)$. 
Any help with good explanation would be wonderful!!! 
Here's what I've tried:
Need to show: 
3(n+1)^2 + 3(n+1) + 1 <= 2(3^(n+1))
= 3n^2 + 9n + 7
= 3n^2 + 3n + 1 + 6n + 6
<= 2(3^n) + 6n + 6 (By inductive Hypoth.)

Comment: I should have said for all n>3

Comment: My original problem was to prove that n^3<=3^n for all natural numbers n....

Comment: Absolutely not @dragon.  Exponential > quadratic.  @ Melissa, begin by finding a base case, the first $n$ for which it is true (it is not 1).  Starting at $n=4$, show that it is true for that, and then go from there to try to show that it is true for the next number if it was true for the previous number.

Comment: @dragon: Huh? By direct computation, your conjecture fails for $n=3,4,5$, and probably all greater integers. Surely the exponential eventually outgrows any polynomial?

Comment: @JMoravitz I did try that but keep going in circles. This is how far I keep getting:Need to show: 3(n+1)^2 + 3(n+1) + 1 <= 2(3^(n+1))  = 3n^2 + 9n + 7  = 3n^2 + 3n + 1 + 6n + 6  <= 2(3^n) + 6n + 6 (By inductive Hypoth.)

Comment: @MPW Never mind, I looked at the graph on desmos.com wrong.

Comment: People expect you to show what you have already tried out in your original post. You tried things and gave those information in a comment, better is to place it in your post. Otherwise a question might be downvoted.

Comment: Thanks Pedro. I fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n=4$.  You have then $3n^2 + 3n + 1 = 3\cdot 16 + 3\cdot 4 + 1 = 48 + 12 + 1 = 61 < 162 = 2\cdot 81 = 2\cdot 3^4 = 2\cdot 3^n$

So, our base case is true.

Suppose for our inductive hypothesis that $3n^2+3n+1 \leq 2\cdot 3^n$ for some $n\geq 4$.

You have then: $3(n+1)^2 + 3(n+1)+1 = 3n^2 + 6n + 3 + 3n + 3 + 1 = (3n^2+3n+1) + (6n+6)~~~(\dagger)$

Since $n\geq 4$ you have $6n+6 = 3\cdot 2\cdot n + 5 + 1 < 3\cdot n\cdot n + 3n + 1=3n^2+3n+1$

So, continuing from $(\dagger)$ you have:

$(3n^2+3n+1)+(6n+6) \leq (3n^2+3n+1)+(3n^2+3n+1)=2\cdot (3n^2+3n+1)$

$\leq^{IH}2\cdot (2\cdot 3^n)\leq 3\cdot (2\cdot 3^n) = 2\cdot 3^{n+1}$

This shows that $(3n^2+3n+1\leq 2\cdot 3^n)\wedge (n\geq 4)\Rightarrow (3(n+1)^2+3(n+1)+1\leq 2\cdot 3^{n+1})$, proving the claim for all $n\geq 4$ by induction.

---

The big trick here is to use the fact that $n\geq 4$ to your advantage to compare items of lower order with items of higher order that more easily combine.

Comment: Ok I get how 6n + 6 <= 3n^2 + 3n + 1, but how does (+ 6n+6) then become (* 2)? I'm just such a literal/concrete person so these assumptions are sometimes hard I guess for me to completely grasp at first!

Comment: @Melissa $(3n^2+3n+1)+(6n+6)\leq (3n^2+3n+1)+(3n^2+3n+1)=2\cdot (3n^2+3n+1)$  The middle step was left out as it seemed obvious to me at the time of writing it that it came from the line after the $(\dagger)$ and didn't need to be said.

Comment: Oops ok sorry I get it now. So you're basically using that 6n+6 < 3n^2....... Instead of just literally replacing it with 2.  Ok. It's clicking now. I'm just starting these in class so thank you for the clarification (as trivial as it probably is!).

Comment: Also implicitly stated (which should be clear without proof) is that $3\cdot 2\cdot n \leq 3\cdot n\cdot n$ for $n\geq 4$ and that $5\leq 3n$ for $n\geq 4$.

Comment: Yes I got that part :) thank you though for making sure to clarify!

Comment: In general, when a statement is not *always* true (like this one not being true for $n=1,2$), you need to use what you know about it during the proof (in this case that $n\geq 4$).  Without using the information given, it can often be either very difficult or outright impossible to prove.  There are some times where you are given superfluous information, but in a standard proof-writing course expect to use all of the given information.  (The problem could have asked you to prove "if $n\geq 4$ and Obama is president that $3n^2+3n+\dots$", you won't need to use that Obama is president).

Comment: Ha ha. Ok good advice. Thanks again so much for your help!!!!